# JavaScript development on WildFly/JBoss server

Tags: javascript, java, wildfly, web-deployment

Is there a way for developers to edit and refresh page directly when modifying javascript hosted on WildFly server?

Right now my cycle is compile and package all the html, js, css, java classes/jars into a deployment war file.
I then deploy that war file into the WildFly server. After deployment, I don't see (by doing `grep`) any of my code in the server's directory.

That cycle is somewhat very slow for something that doesn't really need compilation (javascript).

What is the best practice for developers in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is separated front server based on `nginx` for your frontend, that should call your back server API routed by `nginx` too.